# Compare a variable that can have numeric or string as value

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a variable named `Seconds_Behind_Master` from one of my scripts. The problem is that this variable can either have a numeric value or can also take a string `NULL` as its value. Now, when I try to execute this script in shell it gets executed but gives a warning like this:

```
[: Illegal number: NULL
```

I believe it is due to the fact that in this case the value is `NULL` but when it compares it with numeral value `60` it gives this warning. How can I rectify it?

Comment: @minerz029's answer shows the best way for your situation. For other situations, could the variable be any string you can check if its value is a (positive) integer with `[ -z "${Seconds_Behind_Master//[0-9]/}" ]` which simply removes all the digits `[0-9]` and see if it still has something left (`-z` returns `true` if the argument is `null`)

Comment: @minerz: sorry its a test script I edited it again. See now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you should use an [arithmetic evaluation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) - `(( expression ))`:

```bsh
if (( $Seconds_Behind_Master >= 60 )); then
    echo "replication delayed > 60."
elif [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" = "NULL" ]; then
    echo "Delay is Null."
fi
```

---

If you want to respect the standard POSIX, then you can use:

```bsh
if echo $Seconds_Behind_Master | egrep -q '^[0-9]+$' && [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" -ge "60" ] ; then
    echo "replication delayed >= 60."
elif [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" = "NULL" ]; then
    echo "Delay is Null."
fi
```

More about: [Shell - Test a numeric variable](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/28750-shell-test-a-numeric-variable).

Answer (score 1):

Check if the var is `NULL` first, then check if it is `>= 60`. Consider this code:

```bash
if [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" = "NULL" ]; then
    echo "Delay is Null."
elif [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" -ge 60 ] 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "replication delayed >= 60."
else
    echo "Seconds_Behind_Master is neither NULL or >= 60"
fi
```

You can also replace the line

```bash
elif [ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" -ge 60 ] 2>/dev/null; then
```

with

```bash
elif [[ "$Seconds_Behind_Master" -ge 60 ]]; then
```

if you prefer that and are using a shell which supports the `[[` syntax.

Comment: I did and added the NULL condition first. But what will happen if this takes a numeric value say 65 then at the time of comparison it will first come to `NULL` and will this not generate the error again saying NULL is a string and you are comparing it with a number???

Comment: @Tarun It wont error again because it tests if it is NULL first. If it is, then no further comparisons are made. I've tested this code with a value of 65 and it works fine, saying that "replication delayed >= 60"

Comment: @minerz029 This will generate the same error if `Seconds_Behind_Master` is not set or is equal, for example, with `blahblah`.